Mathematically Ranking Football Players
Here is a math problem I thought of.

Suppose there are 100 football players. Let's assume that there is some objective ranking (i.e. true ranking) of these players that exist (e.g. p1 is best, p2 is second best ... p100 is worst). There are no ties in the true ranking

On any given day, a random set of these players come to the gymnasium to play football. They are randomly assigned to teams (the teams are randomly and unevenly divided, e.g. 11 players show up,  team 1 gets 9 players and team 2 gets 2 players) .

These players play a game of football and the final score is recorded.

We  ONLY have access to the final score and which players played on which teams.


I wrote an R program to simulate how this might look like for 100 games (this simulation just splits a subset of the players into 2 teams and randomly assigns a score to both teams as a proof of concept ... in this simulation, the results of the game are random and are not influenced by the true rankings of the players, the rankings of their team mates and the rankings of their opponents):
num_games <- 100

players <- paste0("p", 1:100)

results <- data.frame(game_no = integer(), 
                      team_1 = character(), 
                      team_2 = character(), 
                      score_team_1 = integer(), 
                      score_team_2 = integer(), 
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)



for(game in 1:num_games) {
    n1 <- sample(1:10, 1)
    n2 <- sample(1:10, 1)
    
    team1 <- sample(players, n1)
    remaining_players <- setdiff(players, team1)
    team2 <- sample(remaining_players, n2)
    
    score_team_1 <- sample(0:20, 1)
    score_team_2 <- sample(0:20, 1)
    
   
    team1_str <- paste(team1, collapse = ", ")
    team2_str <- paste(team2, collapse = ", ")
    
    results <- rbind(results, data.frame(game_no = game, 
                                         team_1 = team1_str, 
                                         team_2 = team2_str, 
                                         score_team_1 = score_team_1, 
                                         score_team_2 = score_team_2))
}

head(results)

The game results might look like this:
 game_no                                      team_1                                      team_2 score_team_1 score_team_2
       1           p69, p75, p27, p95, p42, p99, p28                          p35, p34, p92, p90           11            6
       2                     p40, p79, p96, p71, p14                                    p58, p50            2           10
       3                               p60, p91, p99      p49, p90, p28, p97, p78, p80, p44, p51           18            5
       4 p46, p51, p60, p62, p55, p22, p24, p12, p44 p99, p21, p70, p89, p56, p49, p75, p40, p20           12            6
       5      p71, p16, p83, p56, p26, p45, p38, p10                     p44, p11, p42, p57, p32           16           20
       6                                    p64, p19           p20, p79, p34, p39, p66, p38, p73           16           14

I have the following question:

Suppose we have data from 1000 games between these players. We are interested in estimating the individual rankings of each player (i.e. how good is "player x" in isolation). However, we only have information about the performance of players on a given team when playing another set of players.

We assume that the observed performance of players depends on who is on their team and who they are playing against. However, we are not assuming that teams made of more stronger players always perform better (e.g. "too many cooks in the kitchen spoil the broth" - perhaps some players have better synergy with other players, e.g. a team with a strong player and a medium player might win more against a team of 2 strong players)

For example, suppose p1 is best, p2 is second best ... p100 is worst. Let's say we have a matchup between team 1 (p8, p98, p99) vs team 2 (p2, p100). The final score could be 1-8 (team 1 - team 2). Here it would appear that player 100 is a strong player but this is only because he is playing with player 2. On the other hand, it might appear that player8 is a bad player, but this is only because he is playing with 2 really bad players against one of the best players.


Is there any mathematical algorithm (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueSkill) that search through the available data and try to use some elimination/estimation procedure to try and estimate the individual rankings of players based on this set up?
I am wondering if something might exist which adjusts the ranking based on the availability of data we have on each player. For example, suppose player41 usually plays alone or at most with one other player. Presumably, we would be able to get a better idea of player41's ability compared to some other player that generally plays on bigger teams.
Thanks!
References:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradley%E2%80%93Terry_model


This is very complicated.  Your second bullet says the linear ranking of the players is wrong.  You need a model of how one team will fare against another based on the player rankings of each team.  With a lot of data from not too many players you can test your model.  You can even fit parameters of the model to improve it.  Unfortunately, players come and go pretty often, so you won't get lots of games from a small universe of players.

@ Ross: Thank you for your reply! I am just curious how someone would even begin to mathematically analyze a problem like this. I thought maybe something like Bayesian Networks could be useful? Maybe genetic/evolutionary algorithms to search through the dataset? Maybe something on the Reinforcement Learning side?

We have 100 football players, I will call them 100 laboratory-players. You have another big problem. Team 1 gets 9 players and Team 2 gets 2 players... other players are 'existing players'. First step is probably to evaluate if one team who receive many champions will win the game (it means laboratory-players are better than existing players).

It is unclear to me how the individual ranking is supposed to interact with the team-based outcomes. Consider a hypothetical extreme case of a player who loses every match when they're playing solo but wins every match when they're on a team, regardless of who else is on the team. Should this player be ranked high or low in the "objective" ranking?

@ mhum: thank you for your reply!the situation you describe kind of reminds me of the famous NBA basketball player Dennis Rodman (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Rodman) . Dennis Rodman was very good at catching rebounds and I have heard people say "he might not score a single point in a game but still be the reason that his team won". I agree that the problem I am asking is ill-posed and probably needs many assumptions and constraints for it to be even considered to be solved. I was just curious to see how people on this website would approach this problem and what thoughts come to mind

Fundamentally, you have a math modelling problem. You have an idea of an "objective" ranking of each player's individual ability and are trying to infer this ranking from match outcome data. I suggest that the idea of an objective ranking of this type is incompatible with the provided data unless you can work out a model for how individual ability is supposed to be reflected in team play.

Looks like you are trying to infer a signal from the noise. I would start with Bayesian Inference on a Kalman Filter.
